# Grid | Mobile Optimization

Tags: html, css, optimization, grid

I am trying to replicate this style of grid [Desktop Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B12S9.png). I was able to replicate this desktop version above, but What I also need is to create an optimized mobile version. Once the dimensions get to about tablet size it appears as so [Tablet size about 1269x874](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHGsh.png) and then mobile version appears as so [mobile size about 750x874](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KflOi.png). The difference between mobile and tablet is the location of the button. Anyway, what I cannot figure out is how to optimize this and make my code appear as the same. All help is appreciated and thank you in advance.

PS: I also cant figure out how to center my button in its designated square.

PSS: The sizing references was obtained from F12 console

EDIT: I have updated the code to show the media query I have tried

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title></title>
  <style media="screen">
    .grid {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
      grid-column-gap: 1em;
      grid-row-gap: 1em;
      text-align: left;
      color: white;
      font-size: 14px;
      font-family: Open Sans, sans-serif;
    }

    .grid>div {
      background: #a100ff;
      padding: 1em;
    }

    .grid>div:nth-child(odd) {
      background: #ff00c3;
    }
    .button {
      border: none;
      color: white;
      padding: 16px 50px;
      text-align: center;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: inline-block;
      font-size: 14px;
      margin: 4px 2px;
      transition-duration: 0.4s;
      cursor: pointer;
      border-radius: 12px;
      position: center;
    }


    .button2 {
      background-color: white;
      color: black;
      border: 2px solid #008CBA;
      position: absolute;
    }

    .button2:hover {
      background-color: #008CBA;
      color: white;
    }

  @media only screen and (max-width: 1279px) {
    grid{
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 2fr);
      grid-column-gap: 1em;
      grid-row-gap: 1em;
      text-align: left;
      color: white;
      font-size: 14px;
      font-family: Open Sans, sans-serif;
    }
  }

  </style>


</head>

<body>
  <div class="grid">
    <!-- CLASS NUMBER READ LEFT TO RIGHT -->
    <div class="1">
      <p class="quote">"Lingerie is not about seducing men;
        It's about embracing womanhood"<br><br> - Dita Von Teese </p>

    </div>

    <div class="2">
      <p>Image goes here, delete this text</p>
      <img src="" alt="">
    </div>

    <div class="3">
      <p>Image goes here, delete this text</p>
      <img src="" alt="">
    </div>

    <div class="4">
      <p>Image goes here, delete this text</p>
      <img src="" alt="">
    </div>

    <div class="5">
      <button class="button button2"><a href="https://www.subbly.co/checkout/buy/112646">Take Style Quiz</a></button>
    </div>

    <div class="6">
      <p>Image goes here, delete this text</p>
      <img src="" alt="">
    </div>

    <div class="7">
      <p>Image goes here, delete this text</p>
      <img src="" alt="">
    </div>

    <div class="8">
      <p>Image goes here, delete this text</p>
      <img src="" alt="">
    </div>

    <div class="9">
      <p>"My wife and I absolute LOVE our SeductiveBox subscription! This bring more excitement to our love life. Plus this is the
        only subscription that gets unwrapped TWICE!"<br><br> Wendy S.</p>
    </div>

  </div>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I don't see any media queries - what have you tried. Also position: center is not CSS.

Comment: I have updated the code to display what has been tried.

Comment: To start with, you are missing a dot before grid in the media query selector.

Comment: Unfortunately, even after inserting said period, the grid is still not responding. I did check to make sure that the media query was working with a simple background color change, and it is responding. There is just something wrong with the grid code itself.